# Restart activity if response from server failed in andorid

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two class Activity A and Activity B , now I switched from activity A to B , and in activity B onCreate Method I call one service for some data to show in Activity B, in mean time I get time out or any other error . Now I want to show one dialog to user and ask user to retry.

How can i finish activity B and refresh the whole Activity B ?

Also , I my activity is open in background and I want to redirect user from notification click to the same activity , Ho can we achieve this ..

Please help ... Thanks in advance..

Comment: **This is not a coding service**. Please post the relevant code that you have tried and the logcat of the error that you are getting in it.

Comment: Why restart Activity B . Just when the error come show dialog and on retry button click again call the searvice function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't restart the activity re call the sever call when response failed.
simple logic bro.... happy coding.

Comment: What if i need to restart the activity ?? like i ask above ..  my activity is open in background and I want to redirect user from notification click to the same activity. in that scenario how can i finish the same activity and start it again ??

Comment: add intent to same activity....

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

use finish(); if you want to finish last activity.